# time zone error after installation a script

Tags: php, database, timezone, server, cpanel

i'm getting a error message ----------

```
Warning: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in /home/user/public_html/cdemo/_include/lib/lib.php on line 73

Warning: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in /home/user/public_html/cdemo/_include/lib/lib.php on line 74



Error: E_WARNING
URL: http://mywebsite.com/demo/
File: /home/user/public_html/cdemo/_include/lib/db_common.php
Line: 69
Message: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.

Call stack:

File: /home/user/public_html/cdemo/_include/lib/db_common.php (Line: 69)
Function: date

File: /home/user/public_html/cdemo/_include/core/start.php (Line: 199)
Class: DB_Common
Function: connect

File: /home/user/public_html/cdemo/_include/core/main_start.php (Line: 12)
Function: include

File: /home/user/public_html/cdemo/index.php (Line: 15)
Function: include
```

[image]

how to resolve this issue ??

Comment: $sql = 'SET SESSION `sql_mode` = "", NAMES "utf8", SESSION collation_connection = "utf8_unicode_ci", time_zone = "Indian/Cocos' . date('P') . '"';

Comment: there a line in my database_common directory in db_common.php file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this issue:

1. In the top of your script (or entry file of your mvc framework) use built-in function `date_default_timezone_set(timezone_of_your_place)`. you can find the constant represent your location's timezone in [timezone_list](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) .
2. In `php.ini` Change the config  item `date.timezone = your_timezone`.

The difference of these two is, way 1 will have effect immediately but only in that script's life time, and way 2 will affect all php scripts behavior after reload the php configuration file.

Comment: b_common.php
Line: 46
Message: Can't execute query: Unknown or incorrect time zone: 'Asia/Calcutta+05:30'
SET SESSION `sql_mode` = "", NAMES "utf8", SESSION collation_connection = "utf8_unicode_ci", time_zone = "Asia/Calcutta+05:30"

Comment: now i remove from this line and put in php.ini and working .